# How To Switch To A New View On Simple Button Click?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am simply trying to open up a new view when the user clicks a button. What is the most simple, and easiest way to do this using Swift API?

```
  //Login Button
            Button(
                action:
                {
                // Open Signup Screen
                    Signup();
                },
                label:
                {
                // How the button looks li
                Text("Create New Account")
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .font(.title)
                }
                )
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color(red: 0.22, green: 0.655, blue: 0.02))
                .cornerRadius(8)
                .padding(.horizontal, metrics.size.width*0.10)
            
        }
```

Thanks.

Isaiah Thompson

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please study [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui), and I would also highly recommend auditing [Stanford's CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu).

Comment: Search for "NavigationLink SwiftUI" and/or "SwiftUI programatic navigation"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use a `NavigationLink` and wrapping the content inside a `NavigationView`.

The `NavigationView` is used to represent the view hierarchy.

For instance:

```swift
// Wrapper for LogIn
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
      NavigationView { LogIn() }
    }
}

// LogIn
struct LogIn: View {
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      // Fields for log in

      NavigationLink(destination: SignUp()) {
        Text("Create New Account")
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .font(.title)
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
          .background(Color(red: 0.22, green: 0.655, blue: 0.02))
          .cornerRadius(8)
          .padding(.horizontal, metrics.size.width*0.10)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can find more info in the official docs:

- [NavigationView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationview)
- [NavigationLink](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink)

Also [Hacking With Swift] (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/displaying-a-detail-screen-with-navigationlink) is a great resource for SwiftUI

Comment: Thank you very much! The code is also very clean

Answer (score 0):

```
Button {
  showLoginView = true
} label: {
 Text("Login")
}
NavigationLink("", destination:  LoginView(), isActive: $showLoginView)
```